# How to calculate the number of columns considering blank columns in between?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I calculate the number of columns if `df` has a blank space between some columns? I create `df` based on XLS file, which has such issue. 
The number of blank columns is unknown but never exceeds 20.

```
df =

col1   col2   col3        col4
112    ret    56          xx
34     wet    45          yy
```

How can I calculate the number of columns:
 * to get 4 columns (without considering the blank one)
 * to get 5 columns (considering the blank one).

The approach should work with any number of blank columns between non-blank columns.

UPDATE:

The pandas DataFrame `df` is created as follows:

```
f_path = "C://test/myfile_with_blank_columns.xls"
df = pd.read_excel(open(f_path,'rb'), sheet_name='goal')
```

Data sample (some files do not contain headers):

```
0   0   24.1    23.9    24.4    24.3                            2.880136
0   0   24.1    23.9    24.4    24.3                            2.878689
0   0   24.1    23.9    24.4    24.3                            2.875072
0   0   24.1    23.9    24.4    24.3                            2.883029
```

Comment: uhm the blank column doesn't even have a name?

Comment: @MohitMotwani: Right, that's the issue of the source data that I cannot change.

Comment: You need to provide a way of constructing this DataFrame so we can understand the problem.

Comment: See my answer below: please provide further clarification of the blank columns.

Comment: @FChm: Please see my update.

Comment: Hi, I think my second option (answer below) will work quite generally.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the blank columns are formatted. For example, consider the case where they are empty strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 
                   '' : ['','',''], 
                   'B': [1,2,3]})
```

**Option 1:**

You could try something like count the number of empty columns:

```
df_columns = list(df.columns)

num_cols = len(df_columns) - df_columns.count('')

print(num_cols)
# returns 2
```

**Option 2:**

Another option is to use the [`.isidentifier()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) string method, this will be a little bit more robust as it will detect both empty strings and spaces as blank columns. It will however filter out any columns with a space in! So this again will only work if you have nicely formatted column names for your non-empty columns.

```
num_cols = np.sum([col.isidentifier() for col in df.columns])

print(num_cols)
# prints 2
```

Comment: Sorry, but Option 1 does not work for me. Please see my update to see an example of the data.

Comment: col.isidentifier() needs a header, right? I didn't say that sorry, some files do not contain headers.

Comment: I printed out `df_columns`. Indeed the blank columns get the names `'Unnamed: 89',
 'Unnamed: 90',
 'Unnamed: 91',
 'Unnamed: 92',
 'Unnamed: 93',
 'Unnamed: 94'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is Simple Solution

```
dff = pd.read_excel('D:/test.xlsx',sheet_name='goal',header=None, na_values=' ') #This will convert blank values to NaN

dff 

   0  1     2     3     4     5   6   7   8         9
0  0  0  24.1  23.9  24.4  24.3 NaN NaN NaN  2.880136
1  0  0  24.1  23.9  24.4  24.3 NaN NaN NaN  2.878689
2  0  0  24.1  23.9  24.4  24.3 NaN NaN NaN  2.875072
3  0  0  24.1  23.9  24.4  24.3 NaN NaN NaN  2.883029
```

Get columns (without considering the blank one)

```
col = list(dff.drop(dff.loc[:,list((100*(dff.isnull().sum()/len(dff.index))==100))].columns, 1).columns.values)
print(col)

# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]

print(len(col))

# 7
```

Get columns (considering the blank one)

```
all_col = dff.columns.tolist()
print(all_col)

# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(len(all_col))

# 10
```

*Note: You can create separate dataframe without blank columns*

```
df1 = dff[col]
df1

   0  1     2     3     4     5         9
0  0  0  24.1  23.9  24.4  24.3  2.880136
1  0  0  24.1  23.9  24.4  24.3  2.878689
2  0  0  24.1  23.9  24.4  24.3  2.875072
3  0  0  24.1  23.9  24.4  24.3  2.883029
```